# how to show the middle cell of a collection view when my app starts

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView embedded in a subview of the ViewController. The collectionView has 12 cells. Each cell takes up the whole width and height of the collection view, so that I can achieve the pagination affect. However, when the app starts, I want to show the middle cell like the 6th or 7th one of my collectionView.

P.S. I have the collectionView in a wrapper view, not in my viewController.

In my WrapperView, I added the following method but as this method is called after the collectionView is added, it shows a sudden jump.

```
override func didAddSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
        super.didAddSubview(subview)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 6, section: 0)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.calendarCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
         }
}
```

If I could do it before the collection view appear on the screen, I may be able to fix that problem, but I can't find which method is called before the `didAddSubview(_:)` method in UIView Life Cycle.

Can anyone give me hint on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

After your data source has loaded use:

```
func selectItem(at indexPath: IndexPath?, 
   animated: Bool, 
   scrollPosition: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618057-selectitem

Probably best used before the view appears so trigger in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad`

Comment: My collectionView is in a view, not the controller. So, how can I make sure that the cell that will be shown is the middle one.

Comment: I edited my question. I almost got the effect but there is a jump as it is set after the subView which is my collectionView is added.

Comment: If you dont want the jump to be visible keep the collection 0 opacity until after you set the index. Use `UIViewAnimation.animateWithDuration(0.25) { cv.alpha = 1 } ` to make the fade in less abrupt.